# Get all pods except the pods inside kube-system

Tags: kubernetes

When I do

```
kubectl get pods -A
```

I get all pods, and I always have 17 pods that are not "apps", they belong to namespace `kube-system`. I would like to have an alias not to print them.

Is there a way to print all pods, excluding a namespace ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can accomplish this via [field selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/):

```
kubectl get pods -A --field-selector=metadata.namespace!=kube-system
```

Additionally, the field selector list can have multiple parameters, separated by `,` (comma literals), and use `==` or `!=` to specify additional criteria.

Comment: Interesting that two members with 12.3k rep arrive at the same response within the same minute :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `--field-selector`

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector metadata.namespace!=kube-system
```

more about field selectors here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/